# Is BeginGetHostAddresses async callback called in another thread than the initial

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, asynccallback

My task is to parse huge file log so performance is important. For each log line:
I am calling `Dns.GetHostAddresses` to get ip address by host name and set it to one of the fields for my model.

`result.Ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(result.Host)[0].MapToIPv6().ToString();
// Other code and save result to data base`

and save result model to data base afterwords.

Sometimes `GetHostAddresses` throws `"No such host is known"` exception so the easiest way was to put it in `try{}catch{}` block. But as far as I know - this block slows-down performance. So I found that there is `Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses` method as well. So I tried using it and test if async callback is not called before `result` model is saved to database:

`Dns.BeginGetHostAddresses(result.Host, (x) =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                    // Thread.Sleep(10000);
                     IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(x);
                   //  Thread.Sleep(10000);
                     IPAddress address = addresses[0];
                     result.Ip = address?.MapToIPv6().ToString();
                 }
                 catch { }
             }, null);
           // Other code and save result to data base`

I saw that in this way performance is much higher than when `Dns.GetHostAddresses` is used.
Using debugger I saw that callback is always completed before going to next lines of code. But still not sure if this is side effect of debugging or is it a real state.

My question is:

**Is `async callback` called in another thread and there could be a situation when my model - `result` is saved to database before field `Ip` is set?**